# Formula field in Campaign Member Section

Tags: trigger, workflow, formula, campaign-member

I don't know if this is possible to do with formula but lets try. I am trying to develop a formula that will give me the times opened from certain lead that is under campaign.

What i am trying to accomplish here is to get the value directly from the report and import it into a field in the Campaign Member section.

If this is not possible with formula can someone guide me how I can accomplish this, somehow?

Please advise,

Darko

Comment: With "times opened" you mean an email that was send?

Comment: Yes @RobinDeBondt